# GraphQL variable combination validation

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Imagine the following (simplified) GraphQL schema:

```
type User {
  username: String
  email: String
}

type Query {
  user(username: String, email: String): User
}
```

If I would only want to allow querying `user` by giving a `username`, I would of course change it to `user(username: String!)`, making the `username` required using the exclamation mark. Same thing vice versa with the email.

Is it possible though to have a **GraphQL native** solution where I validate for the existence of only either one (logical XOR) or at least one (logical OR) of the two input parameters?
Of course I could do it in the query resolver manually, but a `@constraint` directive like it is being used in Apollo GraphQL spreading across variables would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Directly ... not possible**:

- check fields existence [within args] on resolver;
- use `@constraint` to check each field shape;

**Indirectly**:

- you can try to use `union` of input types:

.

```
type UserNameInput {
  username: String!
}
type UserEmailInput {
  email: String!
}
type UserInput = UserNameInput | UserEmailInput

type Query {
  user(input: UserInput): User
}
```